# Are there javadoc-like tools to generate RESTful web service apidoc from JAX-RS annotations?

Tags: java, rest, documentation, jax-rs

I'm developing a web service with CXF by using JAX-RS annotations on resources. These annotations specify arguments names, default values, and the valid input and output mime types.

It'd be nice to be able to run a javadoc-esque tool on my code to generate a concise set of documentation of this interface, but I cannot seem to find anything.

The docs produced by javadoc itself would require too much trimming down, I really want something that understands the semantics of the JAX-RS annotations and generates something friendly to the devs who want to use my service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are building Restful webservices, the documentation is known as [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language). WADL is basically Rest's version of WSDL. I use [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) to build my Restful web services. Jersey automatically creates the WADL based on the annotations you have in your resources package. Here's how the sample WADL looks like from Jersey's website: 
https://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/show/trunk/jersey/samples/generate-wadl

The best part of this is you do absolutely nothing. :) When you change the URI or parameters annotation in your `Resource` classes, they will be automatically reflected in this documentation.

TADAA! :)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I hadn't heard about WADL, so that helped, but I was really looking for something human-readable. There are XSLT stylesheets out there for transforming WADL to HTML, such as https://github.com/mnot/wadl_stylesheets

Comment: How do you tell Jersey that @GET(/foo) means "retrieve business object bar" and @QueryParam(name="bla") means "Provide start date in milliseconds" ) ?

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at [Enunciate](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/). There's a [Maven plugin](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/executables.html#maven) that will generate docs included in the site.

Comment: Nice! Maven integration - I'm in.

Comment: Nice, except it does not support Multiple @FormDataParam arguments.