# Generating API documentation from RESTEasy Annotations

Tags: javadoc, documentation-generation, resteasy

I have a set of Java classes that are annotated with RESTEasy annotations.  What I want is to generate JavaDoc like HTML documentation that takes my API interface and shows how to call the API (eg: GET URL) with appropriate inputs and outputs (which are Objects marshalled to/from JSON).

Is there a tool that exists that does this?

Comment: Thinking about this some more, what I may be after is a WADL like document that can be processed into something pretty.  Maybe RESTEasy (or another JBoss tool) could create a WADL from the code?

Comment: this might answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975525/are-there-javadoc-like-tools-to-generate-restful-web-service-apidoc-from-jax-rs

Comment: I'll have to look into Enunciate.  Thanks.